# Write UIImage to Saved photo albums with EXIF

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, exif

I encounter the following problem when using UIImageWriteToSavedPhotoAlbum and the EXIF data is lost.

```
UIImage * image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:recevedData];
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum (image, self, @selector(myselector:), nil);
```

`receivedData` is a complete JPG file received remotely. The JPG file has all the Exif information inside. However after using `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` to save to photo albums I realize there is no more EXIF stored. Is this because of `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` or because of `UIImage` stripping of all the EXIF?

Answer (score 3):

See assets library framework to save images with EXIF-data.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:) , nil);

- (void) image:(UIImage *) image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *) error contextInfo:(void *) contextInfo {
    if ([image isEqual:image]) {
        if (error) {
            // Handle the error...
        }else {
            // saved succesfully
        }
    }else if (image == nil) {
        // no image was provided
    }
}
```

Apple documentation recommends above format for the selector. It may be not solve your problem, but you will know whats happening.

Comment: Sorry there was typo in my code for the selector. Yes, thanks for pointing out. However, it is not because of the selector. I think UIImage strip off all EXIF data.

Comment: You can use the error object to know the error. you can NSLog [error localizedDescription] and see whats the matter. To be more sure, try to display that image in some imageView.

Comment: I doubt there is an error saving it. It's just lost metadata.

Comment: Yep, that was one of his problem. So i asked him to check out if the image received is proper, displaying in some image view.

Comment: No problem displaying. The exif data of the original image totally stripped off by UIImage.

Comment: My generic question is how can we write to photo album without using UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum? That is now I have NSData and i want to write directly to photo album as it is without going through UIImage.

Comment: i have not yet encountered any other way to do so, and i doubt if it exists. you need to make uiimage without losing that exif data.